# Long protobuf to poro serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, protocol-buffers

I am trying to compare protobuf and json data exchange speed between two ruby microservices. As I thought protobuf is much faster in most of cases. As the final test I want to check if converting decoded Message proto class to some poro will be faster than doing the same using json.

Here is an example of conversion with json:

```
  def self.map_all_posts_from_json(data)
    RubyProf.start
    data.map do |post|
      Post.new.tap do |new_post|
        new_post.id = post["id"]
        new_post.description = post["description"]
        new_post.content = post["content"]
        new_post.rating = post["rating"]
        new_post.user = User.new.tap do |new_user|
          new_user.id = post["user"]["id"]
          new_user.name = post["user"]["name"]
          new_user.surname = post["user"]["surname"]
          new_user.nickname = post["user"]["nickname"]
        end
        new_post.comments = post["comments"].map do |comment|
          Comment.new.tap do |new_comment|
            new_comment.id = comment["id"]
            new_comment.content = comment["content"]
            new_comment.rating = comment["rating"]
            new_comment.user = User.new.tap do |new_user|
              new_user.id = comment["user"]["id"]
              new_user.name = comment["user"]["name"]
              new_user.surname = comment["user"]["surname"]
              new_user.nickname = comment["user"]["nickname"]
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    result = RubyProf.stop
    printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
    printer.print(STDOUT)
  end
```

and protobuf:

```
  def self.unserialize_all_posts(data)
    RubyProf.start
    data.posts.map do |post|
      Post.from_message(post)
    end
    result = RubyProf.stop
    printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
    printer.print(STDOUT)
  end
```

Post.from_message method:

```
  def self.from_message(message)
    Post.new.tap do |post|
      post.id = message.id
      post.desription = message.description
      post.content = message.content
      post.rating = message.rating
      post.user = User.from_message(message.user)
      post.comments = message.comment_messages.map do |comment|
        Comment.from_message(comment)
      end
    end
  end
```

surprisingly json way was a lot faster. Then I investigated data returned by RubyProf and found out that there were lots and lots of calls to proto_class#method_missing and other suspect methods. Did any of you had similar problem? I am using 'google-protobuf' gem.

[image: RubyProf]

Comment: Protip: you can just use `User.new do |new_user|` without `#tap`. `#new` takes a block and yields the record. But there really is no reason to do `new_comment.id = comment["id"]` unless you feel like being a human compiler since the hash keys match the attribute names. Just use `Hash#slice` or `ActionController::Parameters#permit` and pass the whitelist to `#new`.

Comment: Thank you for that one max. But it still didn't fix method_missing issue